# Node.JS testing DOM with Mocha?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to do some simple view testing in my Node.JS app using the Mocha testing framework...

For example, I want to test that the `<ol>` on the page has `n` `<li>` children, given the number of records I setup in my test.

I tried using [Apricot](https://github.com/silentrob/Apricot) to do this, and while I got it to work, when it fails the error messages are fantastically unhelpful... also, it doesn't always work.

What I'd love is a simple way to test the response body for HTML elements, so I can determine if they match the data they should be displaying.

Here's my test in it's current state: https://gist.github.com/2330685

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What about using the cheerio library you can load in the html as string and then manipulate with the JQuery like selectors.

Comment: @jurka Looks really good! I'll have to play around with it some... thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @jurka This is great! Exactly what I was looking for. Can you repost your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting the comment as answer as well.

For DOM manipulation or element finding, I am suggesting the great library [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio), which can load the html as string and then use jQuery-like selectors. Also it seems to be really lightweight. I replaced the JSDOM with request + cheerio combination.